# Gonum throws bad region panic when using an embedded struct

Tags: go, struct, gonum

I am using gonum to perform a few linear algebra calculations. After extending the original `mat.VecDense` struct I am getting a "bad region: identical" panic when applying a method on itself. This error does not occur when I am using the original setup gonum provides.

Here is my implementation:

```
type Vector struct {
    mat.VecDense
}
func NewVector(n int, data []float64) *Vector {
    return &Vector{*mat.NewVecDense(n, data)}
}
```

I am testing it using the following snippet:

```
func main() {
    u, v := mat.NewVecDense(3, []float64{1, 2, 3}), mat.NewVecDense(3, []float64{4, 5, 6})
    fmt.Printf("[U - NewVecDense]\tADDRESS: %v, VALUE: %v\n", &u, u)
    fmt.Printf("[V - NewVecDense]\tADDRESS: %v, VALUE: %v\n", &v, v)
    u.AddVec(u, v)

    fmt.Println("-------------------------")
    x, y := NewVector(3, []float64{1, 2, 3}), NewVector(3, []float64{4, 5, 6})
    fmt.Printf("[X - NewVector]\tADDRESS: %v, VALUE: %v\n", &x, x)
    fmt.Printf("[Y - NewVector]\tADDRESS: %v, VALUE: %v\n", &y, y)
    x.AddVec(x, y)
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

While the first addition executes fine, the second fails:

```
[U - NewVecDense]   ADDRESS: 0xc42000c028, VALUE: &{{[1 2 3] 1} 3}
[V - NewVecDense]   ADDRESS: 0xc42000c030, VALUE: &{{[4 5 6] 1} 3}
-------------------------
[X - NewVector] ADDRESS: 0xc42000c040, VALUE: &{{{[1 2 3] 1} 3}}
[Y - NewVector] ADDRESS: 0xc42000c048, VALUE: &{{{[4 5 6] 1} 3}}
panic: mat: bad region: identical
```

`AddVec` is a method [implemented by gonum](https://github.com/gonum/gonum/blob/master/mat/vector.go#L333):

```
func (v *VecDense) AddVec(a, b Vector)
```

Why is this happening, hand what is the right way of implementing this?

---

Edit:

Thanks to @Himanshu I managed to solve the problem.

I created pass-through methods for each method I am using, passing the right level of the struct through:

```
type Vector struct {
    *mat.VecDense
}

func NewVector(n int, data []float64) Vector {
    return Vector{mat.NewVecDense(n, data)}
}

func (v *Vector) AddVec(a, b Vector) {
    v.VecDense.AddVec(a.VecDense, b.VecDense)
}

func (v *Vector) SubVec(a, b Vector) {
    v.VecDense.SubVec(a.VecDense, b.VecDense)
}

func (v *Vector) ScaleVec(alpha float64, a Vector) {
    v.VecDense.ScaleVec(alpha, a.VecDense)
}

func (v *Vector) AddScaledVec(a Vector, alpha float64, b Vector) {
    v.VecDense.AddScaledVec(a.VecDense, alpha, b.VecDense)
}
```

In addition - I am not sure if this is the right approach or not - I have also changed the return type for `NewVector` from pointer to value, since it holds a pointer to the `mat.VecDense` anyway. Note that `*mat.VecDense` satisfies the `Vector` interface from gonum, so passing this internal field on to the methods worked fine, as the example above shows.

Comment: Please post the code for `AddVec` function where you are passing the Vector struct.

Comment: `AddVec` is implemented by gonum: https://github.com/gonum/gonum/blob/master/mat/vector.go#L333. I'll update the main post with this refernece.

Comment: Probably I am doing something very dumb. However, following your pointers I got to the following solution, which actually works: `func (v *Vector) AddVec(a *Vector, b *Vector) {
 v.VecDense.AddVec(&a.VecDense, &b.VecDense)
}
`

Comment: This is what I have provided in the example to use the function with embedded struct and using pointer type arguments to `AddVec`. Please check my answer and the link.

Comment: Now what you changed is you are passing a pointer to the struct which I have edited that the argument should be of pointer to `Vector`.

Comment: Methods on embedded structs are promoted, unless overwritten on the parent struct. Also note that there is a difference between my `Vector` definition (which is a struct embedding VecDense), and the `Vector` interface, which the gonum `AddVec` expects.

Comment: It looks to me like to are trying to fit Go into a class-based like solution. Why are you trying to extend `*VecDense`? The appropriate approach would be to add functions that take the types as parameters.

Comment: @kortschak there was no particular concept in doing so, I am learning Golang and perhaps my OO experience has skewed my approach. My goal was to have a linear algebra package, that we can internally use, and that builds on top of gonum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Golang it is described for promoted methods as

> Promoted fields act like ordinary fields of a struct except that they
>   cannot be used as field names in composite literals of the struct.

Given a struct type S and a defined type T, promoted methods are included in the method set of the struct as follows:

- If S contains an embedded field T, the method sets of S and *S both include promoted methods with receiver T. The method set of *S also includes promoted methods with receiver *T.
- If S contains an embedded field *T, the method sets of S and *S both include promoted methods with receiver T or *T.

The problem is that you are passing pointer type arguments to `AddVec` function. But you are using pointer type fields in second case.

```
func (v *VecDense) AddVec(a, b Vector)
```

One more thing to notice is that `AddVec` has value type arguments of `Vector` struct but you are passing pointer to `Vector` fields as

```
x, y := NewVector(3, []float64{1, 2, 3}), NewVector(3, []float64{4, 5, 6})
```

In above code `x,y` are pointer type returned from `NewVector`

```
x.AddVec(x, y)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but if the type were incompatible, would the code not even compile? `Vector` embeds the `VecDense` struct, so I can use the methods of the original struct.

Comment: @BalazsDianiska try to embed the struct with an example and check if you can do that or not. you can but by calling the name of the parent embedded struct.

Comment: thanks for the tip, unfortunately the issue remains.

Comment: @BalazsDianiska I have noticed one more thing which is that `NewVector` returns pointer while the arguments to `AddVec` is of value type.

Comment: @BalazsDianiska yes that's why I have changed the answer and edited that the problem was when passing the arguments to the `AddVec` method not with the receiver. I know the method of embedded struct is promted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the pointers are compared when doing shadow detection. This is a bug IMO. I just filed https://github.com/gonum/gonum/issues/945